# Getting an error when attempting to use FFmpeg to copy primary AC3 audio to aac_he secondary audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to add secondary audio with FFmpeg to copy my primary audio over and encode it with libfdk_aac using profile aac_he. When I do, I am getting the following errors:

[NULL @ 000001f4d7830b80] [Eval @ 0000003fb93fdf50] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'aac_he'
[NULL @ 000001f4d7830b80] Unable to parse option value "aac_he"
[NULL @ 000001f4d7830b80] Error setting option profile to value aac_he.
Error setting up codec context options.
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --*
Here is the command I am trying to use:

ffmpeg -y -fflags -genpts -i -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a:0 copy -map 0:a -c:a:1 libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he e:\nf.ts
I would expect it to copy the Primary audio to Audio 1 (AC3), and then re-encode the audio from Audio 1 to to Audio 2 (aac_he).

If I only use aac native audio, instead of aac_he, it works fine using this command:

ffmpeg -y -fflags -genpts -i %%f -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a:0 copy -map 0:a -c:a:1 aac e:\nf.ts
From this, I get Audio 1 (AC3) and Audio 2(aac).

or it works if I just re-encode the primary audio like using this command:

ffmpeg -y -fflags -genpts -i %%f -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he e:\nf.ts
From this, I get Audio 1(aac_he)

Is there something about using the aac_he in the secondary audio position that ffmpeg has issues with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-profile:a aac_he` applies to *all* output audio streams. Apply it to only the intended stream; `-profile:a:1 aac_he`.